# How do I fix this webscraper made using puppeteer which is doing nothing after scraping half data but not giving any error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

For my college project, I made a Wikipedia scraper using nodejs and puppeteer. It's working for all but one link. After scraping almost half the data of a table in that page (I am using the console.log to see which data has been scraped at that moment) it just does nothing. It does not show any error. It does not stop executing, it just does nothing after that. The puppeteer browser does not close either.

In the original scraper, I used a loop of links to generate data. As it was not working so I made a separate scraper for that link but the same thing is happening. Can anyone help me out?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');


(async () => {

try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 });

    link = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_June_2016";

    console.log("==============================");
    console.log("Travelling to link:", link);
    console.log("==============================");

    await page.goto(link, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});

    let rowArray = await page.$$("table[class='wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'] > tbody > tr");

    var dataA = [];

    for(let row of rowArray){
        let date = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(1)', element => element.textContent);
        date = date.substring(0, date.length - 1);
        let type = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(2)', element => element.textContent);
        type = type.substring(0, type.length - 1);
        let dead = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(3)', element => element.textContent);
        dead = dead.substring(0, dead.length - 1);
        let injured = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(4)', element => element.textContent);
        injured = injured.substring(0, injured.length - 1);
        let location = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(5)', element => element.textContent);
        location = location.substring(0, location.length - 1);
        let details = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(6)', element => element.textContent);
        details = details.substring(0, details.length - 1);
        let perpetrator = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(7)', element => element.textContent);
        perpetrator = perpetrator.substring(0, perpetrator.length - 1);
        let partOf = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(8)', element => element.textContent);
        partOf = partOf.substring(0, partOf.length - 1);
        


        console.log("==============================");
        console.log({date, type, dead, injured, location, details, perpetrator, partOf});
        console.log("==============================");

        dataA.push({date, type, dead, injured, location, details, perpetrator, partOf});
    }

    console.log("==============================");
    console.log("Started writing JSON file");
    fs.writeFileSync(`./june.json`, JSON.stringify(dataA), 'utf-8');
    console.log("Finished writing JSON file");
    console.log("==============================");


    await browser.close();

} catch (error) {
    console.error();
}

})();
```

Comment: Wikipedia is human-edited. You shouldn't try to scrape it because there's no structure there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at the point where it stops
[image: it stops here]

It seems the script struggles with the next row which doesn't have a "closing cell"

My guess is if you edit that page and close it it will work (or update your script to handle that scenario)

Looking at the Wikipedia source, in that row the "part of" cell is missing, thus your code just hangs in the 'await' section

```
    let partOf = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(8)', element => element.textContent);
```

Thus you get no errors.

Comment: Is there any way to break out of that await state in that row?

Comment: I managed to fix the bug. Thanks for the help man.

            if (await row.$('td:nth-child(8)') != null) {
                partOf = await row.$eval('td:nth-child(8)', element => element.textContent);
                partOf = partOf.substring(0, partOf.length - 1);
            }
            else {
                partOf = "";
            }